# Django - cant creat directory in settings.py - Apache2

Tags: django, apache2, centos7

I work to put in prod mode a Django website.
I stuck in Error Permission for create a folder by my settings.py.

I cant in my `settings.py` create a directory... why ? =(

## Error log

(i remove not useful informations)

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=440685): Failed to exec Python script file '/PATHMYSITE/wsgi.py'.
 mod_wsgi (pid=440685): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/PATHMYSITE/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/PATHMYSITE/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/PATHMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/PATHMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
   File "/PATHMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "/PATHMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/PATHMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/PATHMYSITE/MYSITE/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
      from .settings import DEBUG
   File "/PATHMYSITE/MYSITE/settings.py", line 333, in <module>
      os.mkdir(FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/PATHMYSITE/media/tmp'
```

## Django "settings.py"

```
#### many things ######

FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "tmp")

if not os.path.exists(FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR):
    os.mkdir(FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR)
```

## Apache Httpd "django.conf"

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /PATHMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

CustomLog logs/MYSITE-access_log common
ErrorLog logs/MYSITE-error_log


#<VirtualHost *:80>


        # ServerName www.DNS.com:80

        WSGIDaemonProcess MYSITE python-home=/PATHMYENV python-path=/PATHMYSITE
        WSGIProcessGroup MYSITE

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /PATHMYSITE/MYSITE/wsgi.py

        Alias /static/ /PATHMYSITE/static/
        <Directory /PATHMYSITE/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /PATHMYSITE>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /PATHMYSITE/MYSITE>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

#</VirtualHost>
```

### EDIT 1 - Permission SITE folder

```
[ME@web PATHTOMYPARENTFOLDERSITE]$ ls -Z 
drwxrwxr-x. apache  apache  unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 MYSITE
drwxr-xr-x. apache  apache  unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 MYENV
```

Comment: Look at which user owns the directories. apache typically runs as the apache user. If you installed your django project under the root user, or any user other that apache but with wrong file/directory permissions you're going to have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ownership of directory where your docroot is located to the user who is running apache. If you are running apache with "apache2" user then do following

```
# chown -R apache2:apache /PATHMYSITE/MYSITE/
```

and restart

```
# service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i already did it with the user apache. `chown -R apache:apache /PATHMYSITE/MYSITE/`. And the restart that word for me is `sudo systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: That is the same thing. You are restarting apache. Nowadays systemctl are used to restart services.

Comment: ok. So i did what you suggested, no ? if you did more information, please tell me.

Comment: If shutting down selinux don't have any issue for you then can you try this command to make selinux in permissive mode? # setenforce Permissive

Comment: with `sudo setenforce Permissive` it's worked. Thanks for that tips (turn off SELinux)... now i am blocked on the fact. That when i upload a file it does not write in my targeted tmp folder...

Comment: Do you get any error message? Does it write on a different directory?

Comment: just 403 error. I try to solve it with the django debug help (`DEBUG=True`). But it seems to be very weird for me (to many problems/difference between dev and prod env)... I will make an another post about it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve by the comment of `Manish R` with this command line:

`sudo setenforce Permissive`

It turns off SELinux.